# Oracle Conditional Index with two identifiers

Tags: oracle, indexing

Is it possible to create a conditional index on two columns?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_dup_wfc
    ON WF_WORKFLOW_CLASS (CASE WHEN is_active = 1
      THEN (NAME, DEPT_OWNER)
         ELSE NULL
      END)
```

returns `ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis` however the following works

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_dup_wfc
    ON WF_WORKFLOW_CLASS (CASE WHEN is_active = 1
      THEN NAME
         ELSE NULL
      END)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you have to perform a CASE per column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_dup_wfc
    ON WF_WORKFLOW_CLASS 
     (CASE WHEN is_active = 1 THEN NAME END
     ,CASE WHEN is_active = 1 THEN DEPT_OWNER END
     )
```

(The ELSE in your code is superfluous).